# How to loop through csv file numeric data in python 3.11

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with one column of numeric values (many rows) and I want to loop through the rows of the csv file as numeric for further processing. Let's say I want to find the min and max values for example.

Edit: Adding specific use case for clarity, my csv file is oscilloscope voltage readings from 0.12 seconds of composite video (6 million points or csv rows). I will need to identify when a new field starts and begin processing data from that point because I want to recreate a single field pixel by pixel into an image file. Later on I'm going to work on "cleaning up" the composite signal and I'm using this as non real-time testing.

I was able to load my csv file and print the data using example code below, but it appears to be a single string versus rows of numeric data.

```
import csv
with open('ExampleFile.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

A few rows of data from the csv file:
1.65
1.71
1.49
1.33
1.06
0.703
0.301
0.261
0.442
0.622
0.723
0.683
0.843
1.2
1.63
1.71
1.49
1.31
1.04
0.663

[image]

Comment: Use `int()` or `float()` to convert that column to a number.

Comment: E.g. `int(row[2])` will convert the 3rd column in the CSV to an integer.

Comment: It would help to know what *I will need to identify when a new field starts and begin processing data from that point ...* means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a CSV file if it only has a single column... Either way, the `csv` module doesn't parse numbers for you (and that's a good thing – see how Excel mangles your data if it feels like it...).

Here's an example that extends your code to parse the zeroth column as a number, and keeps track of the minimum and maximum (without having to read all of the file into memory at once).

```
import csv
min_value = None
max_value = None
with open('ExampleFile.csv', newline='') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        value = float(row[0])  # interpret column as a floating point number
        if min_value is None or value < min_value:
            min_value = value
        if max_value is None or value > max_value:
            max_value = value

print(f"{min_value=}, {max_value=}")
```

If the file is small and you don't mind reading it all into memory and doing two passes over the data to get the minimum and maximum, things become simpler with a list comprehension to loop over the file:

```
import csv

with open('ExampleFile.csv', newline='') as f:
    # Interpret zeroth column of all rows as a float,
    # store them in a list
    values = [float(row[0]) for row in csv.reader(f)]

min_value = min(values)
max_value = max(values)

print(f"{min_value=}, {max_value=}")
```

Comment: I feel like I'm using "row" and "column" backwards; are the meanings different from a csv file versus in code?

Also, I added a bit more context to my intended use of the data in my question if that helps. Thank you.

Comment: @forkram Could you paste in a part of your file to your question?

Comment: added some data and a screen shot above

Comment: Right, that file should work fine with this code.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a single column CSV file per [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) [CSV definition](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#page-2): *Within the header and each record, there may be one or more fields, separated by commas.  ... The last field in the record must not be followed by a comma.*

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html) to handle your csv file and infer column data type, especially if you want apply some data processing:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('ExampleFile.csv')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Car   Color  Value
0   A     red     10
1   B    blue     30
2   C  yellow     40

>>> df.dtypes
Car      object
Color    object
Value     int64  # <- detected as numeric
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually have only one column of data.

```
cat single_col.csv
1
2
3
4
5

import csv

with open('single_col.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    c_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=' ')
    for row in c_reader:
        print(float(row[0]))
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
```